# Showing only the first custom label. Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have super weird bug in my program that i cant crack for a while now. Basically i am using Highcharts.js and when i try to make a simple line chart with custom labels parsed in formatter it shows only the first custom label that is ithe array. The first chart library that i used was Google charts and there i was encountering the exactly same problem. The data that i am getting from the server is completely correct and tested with Postman for errors. Here is the code responsible for creating the chart.

```
$("#table tbody").on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = table.row(this).data();

    $(".diagrams-row").html('<div class="loader"></div><span class="loading-label">Generating diagrams for a pair of stocks: ' + data[0] + '</span>');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/generateDiagrams?name=" + data[0] + "&periods=" + getParameterByName("periods"),
        method: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            $(".diagrams-row").html('');

            $(".diagrams-row").append(
                $("<div/>")
                    .attr("id", "chart_div")
            );

            var myLabels = [result.average - result.standartDeviation * 3,
            result.average - result.standartDeviation * 2,
            result.average - result.standartDeviation,
            result.average,
            result.average + result.standartDeviation,
            result.average + result.standartDeviation * 2,
            result.average + result.standartDeviation * 3];

            $(function () {
                var myChart = Highcharts.chart('chart_div', {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Number of Employees'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function () {
                                return myLabels[this.value];
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            label: {
                                connectorAllowed: false
                            },
                            pointStart: 2010
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Installation',
                        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
                    }, {
                        name: 'Manufacturing',
                        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
                    }, {
                        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
                        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
                    }, {
                        name: 'Project Development',
                        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
                    }, {
                        name: 'Other',
                        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
                    }],
                    responsive: {
                        rules: [{
                            condition: {
                                maxWidth: 500
                            },
                            chartOptions: {
                                legend: {
                                    layout: 'horizontal',
                                    align: 'center',
                                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is an image of what happens (you can see how it displays only the first label of the yAxis):
[image]

That is the code if you need any more information feel free to ask. There aren't any errors displayed in the console. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be lots easier to debug and help with this with an online demo app in jsfiddle or similar platform.

Comment: I would look at the values returned from the `this.value` call in the formatter. That arrangement will only work if your natural `yAxis` values are 0,1,2,3, etc. With values ranging from thousands to hundreds of thousands, that won't be the case. You would need to return the index rather than the `value`, but I don't know that the index is available

Comment: this.value is the first zero the second time 50000, the third time 100000 and etc.

Comment: @jlbriggs what do you mean return the index. How can i do this.

Comment: So, if your second axis value is 50,000, that's only going to return a value from `myLabels` if you have more than 50,000 entries in that array :) `this.value` isn't going to help you here. I don't see that an index value is available, which is a shame. One potential solution is to calculate and set the `tickPositions` yourself, and use a keyed array with the calculated values.

Comment: @HristianIliev why are you changing the labels of ticks? Maybe would be good to try to use the `yAxis.tickPositions` array or even `yAxis.tickPositioner` function?
Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/1tbc83j0/

Comment: @daniel_s for some reason with oyur numbers it works, but when i put my numbers it doesn;t

Comment: @HristianIliev please provide me with your array with numbers.

Comment: @daniel_s its the same as in the code in the question. Something along the lines of [-4.14, -3.20, -1.69, -0.80, 0.74].

Comment: @daniel_s's values work because he's just setting the tick positions, based on valid y axis values. You're trying to use those valid values for placement, and replace the values to display your deviations. It will need to be more complex to accomplish this. I would consider approaching it differently - determine meaning standard deviations to mark, (-3, -2, -1, 0, +1, +2, +3, etc), calculate what the axis values will be, set your tickpositions using the calculated y axis values, and use the array the way you are now to replace the label values.

Comment: @jlbriggs that seems like so much work for something so little as jsut changing the values for the yAxis. Do you know another library that does this easily. If not i will try to do it with your approach.

Comment: I don't know of one that does, off hand. However, even though it sounds complicated, you're already doing most of the work needed with your calculations. Let me see if I can throw together an example

Comment: @HristianIliev Maybe the way out of that is to setting the labels `innerHTML` basing on its index. Please take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/e41bw9rf/2/

Comment: @daniel_s yes that is setting the labels but it isnt correct. The first value on 'Installation' is 43000 and it is around -3.2 on the yAxis

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it something like this (as mentioned in my comment above):

- calculate your standard deviations
- set an array of those values to use as your `tickPositions` value
- build a keyed object of those values and the corresponding label value that you want

The setup looks something like this:

```
tickPositions = [-67982,-33176,1629,36435,71241,106046,140852,175658],
myLabels = {};

myLabels[-67982]='-3';
myLabels[-33176]='-2';
myLabels[1629]='-1';
myLabels[36435]='Mean';
myLabels[71241]='+1';
myLabels[106046]='+2';
myLabels[140852]='+3';
myLabels[175658]='+4';
```

And the result looks something like this:

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/u4293Lv0/

I put the axis with the updated labels as a secondary axis in my example, but obviously you can set it up however you want.

Comment: thank you. I just figured it out.I set the min value and the max value, set tickamounts and the tickInterval to the standart deviation and that way i get the correct values. Your answer just modifies the displayed numbers and is not correct when looking at the data. For example the alst point in 'Installation' line. It is 154175, but on the modified axis it shows around 3.5.

Comment: scratch that i found better solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51520425/9104246

Comment: The axis on the right is showing the standard deviations, which is what it seems like you were after. I guess I have no idea what you're actually trying to do still...

Answer (score 0):

One of the comment of @daniel_s was the correct one. It turns out that i just ahd to use yAxis.tickPositioner function:

```
$(function () {
                            var myChart = Highcharts.chart('chart_div', {
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
                                },
                                subtitle: {
                                    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                    title: {
                                        text: 'Number of Employees'
                                    },
                                    labels: {
                                        format: '{value:.2f}'
                                    },
                                    tickPositioner: function () {
                                        var positions = [result.average - result.standartDeviation * 3,
                                        result.average - result.standartDeviation * 2,
                                        result.average - result.standartDeviation,
                                        result.average,
                                        result.average + result.standartDeviation,
                                        result.average + result.standartDeviation * 2,
                                        result.average + result.standartDeviation * 3];
                                        return positions;
                                    }
                                },
                                legend: {
                                    layout: 'vertical',
                                    align: 'right',
                                    verticalAlign: 'middle'
                                },
                                plotOptions: {
                                    series: {
                                        label: {
                                            connectorAllowed: false
                                        },
                                        pointStart: 2010
                                    }
                                },
                                series: [{
                                    name: 'Installation',
                                    data: [0, -1, 1, 4, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
                                }, {
                                    name: 'Manufacturing',
                                    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
                                }, {
                                    name: 'Sales & Distribution',
                                    data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
                                }, {
                                    name: 'Project Development',
                                    data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
                                }, {
                                    name: 'Other',
                                    data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
                                }],
                                responsive: {
                                    rules: [{
                                        condition: {
                                            maxWidth: 500
                                        },
                                        chartOptions: {
                                            legend: {
                                                layout: 'horizontal',
                                                align: 'center',
                                                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

Here is the correct display of the chart. [image]

Comment: The result you posted above is what you wanted? You want to cut off the majority of the data? This is a very confusing result.